# Can I use shortcuts inside a repository for yum?

Tags: yum, repository

I'm creating a repository for distributing specific software. I want to be able to store old versions of the software in the repository, but I'd like the users of the repo to not need to specify a version to download the latest. Can I use a shortcut in the directory that simply points to the latest version? Or must a create a second copy of the latest software?

As an example, say I had a package (.rpm) called "example", and I had versions "1.0.0" and "1.1.0". I would like the user to be able to specify their version by:

```
yum install example 1.0.0
```

or

```
yum install example 1.1.0
```

and if they simply:

```
yum install example
```

They would get version "1.1.0", the latest.

So if there were a shortcut in the repo called "example", and this shortcut pointed to "example 1.1.0" would "yum install example" install that file? I don't mind updating the shortcut when adding a new version, I'm just wondering if it would work to avoid duplicating the most recent file. Will yum automatically pick the most recent version without a version specification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have multiple versions in a YUM repo, `yum` will always get the latest version with just a bare `yum install example`.